# How can (if at all) we create this mathematical function?

Tags: functions

How can we create a mathematical $F(x)$ function such that, given an input real number $x$ to the function:

1. $F(x) = 1$ , if $x \neq 0$
2. $F(x) = 0$ , if $x = 0$

Essentially, the function tests if the input is 0 or not.

We are looking a single function in old school mathematics so 'if-else' or Boolean functions etc. are out of question.

Comment: You'll have to be more precise in what an *"function in old school mathematics"* means.

Comment: What do you mean by 'create'? What are we supposed to be creating it out of? Typically functions are 'defined', and what you have written is sufficient to define your function.

Comment: Essentially algebra, calculus etc. Is it possible?

Comment: I would say that you have just created it, ta-da! Now it exists! But what is your concern? Certainly $F$ produces a single and well-defined output for any real input. But it's not continuous, nor is the expression a "single expression" ... So what do you want from it, then?

Comment: Informally speaking, the answer "should" be "no". Algebraic and calculus operations on real numbers are continuous, and therefore they cannot be composed to give a continuous answer. Depending on what exactly you allow you might be able to sneak it in via the floor function, or modular arithmetic, or something like that. Ultimately the problem is more with the question than with the solution: why do you want this? What makes you think you need this? The answer is almost certainly that you don't.

Comment: A function that can be expressed as a single expression that can be part of an integral expression. This is a sub-component of a larger expression that I intend to integrate. So, that is the bottleneck/target.

Comment: Note that your function $F$ is not continuous, so it is impossible to define it using continuous functions.

Comment: As explained in one of the comments above, none of elementary functions (including polynomial, rational, algebraic, trigonometric, exponential, logarithm and their inverse, and any combination of these function using finitely many arithmetic operations and function compositions) will do the job, unless we are allowed to exploit some specific implementation of their behavior along branch-cut. We can define $F$ as $$F(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}, $$ but certainly this not what you want.

Comment: And given your comment, I begin to think that you fell into the [*XY-problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps it is better to ask the original question or at least supply the relevant contexts, which may possibly have an answer in entirely different route than what you may expect.

Comment: Thank you to all for your time and help. I think I am sure it cannot be done (at least the form I expected). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look up the Dirac delta function [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), even though it is probably not the *single function in old school mathematics* you are looking for.

Comment: I downvoted. Although the question was somewhat vague, it clearly specified the function $F$, which differs from Dirac delta (which is in fact not even a function).